# Opencover test coverage Asp.Net application

Tags: asp.net, nunit, opencover

I am trying to generate test coverage on asp.net web application. I am using Nunit and have created test project.

I am running following command

"OpenCover.Console.exe" -output:"coverage_ui.xml" -register:user -target:"nunit3-console.exe" -targetargs:"ApplicationName_Test.dll /framework:net-4.0 /result:TestResult.xml;format=nunit2"

But I am getting following error:

1) Invalid : ApplicationName_Test.dll
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions
 property for more information.

I have **Local Copied** all required references

Comment: When the exception is thrown, do as suggested and look at the LoaderExceptions property of the exception.  It will give you more information.  But the problem will be that in order to run the code you need another assembly to be referenced - something that the code under test references itself, but your test assembly does not

Comment: Do your unit tests run without OpenCover? ASP.NET MVC tests often require special setup in your tests to specify where to load views from and the like...